# Cómo pasar de uint8_t Matriz[6] a una cadena de caracteres matriz o variable uint8_t

Tags: c, matrices, conversión-de-tipos, tipos, operador-de-conversión

Tengo 6 valores almacenados en esta matriz:

```
uint8_t AxisData_Matrix[6];
```

Tengo la siguiente función, lo que devuelva no importa:

```
  * @brief  Sends an amount of data in blocking mode. 
  * @param  pData: Pointer to data buffer
  * @param  Size: Amount of data to be sent
    HAL_UART_Transmit(**INDIFERENTE**, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size, **INDIFERENTE**)
```

Esta función la tengo definida de la siguiente forma:

```
pdata_aux = &AxisData_Matrix[i]
HAL_UART_Transmit(**INDIFERENTE**, pdata_aux, sizeof(AxisData_Matrix[i]), **INDIFERENTE**);
```

**Los valores que están almacenados en AxisData_Matrix[] se transmiten en ASCII, de tal manera, que si AxisData_Matrix[i]= 0x31, el sistema sólo enviará 1, si AxisData_Matrix[i] = 0x05 se enviará un signo de tréboles.**

Necesito enviar, si tengo un 0x31, 31, y si tengo un 0x05, un 05. No sé de qué forma hacer esto, he estado probando con sprintf, y otras tantas formas, y no logro hacer las conversiones necesarias.

Me vendría bien la ayuda de alguien.
Muchas gracias.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dices que si el dato a enviar es `0x31`, lo que envía es `1`. Sospecho que el problema no está en lo que envías (que es verdaderamente un byte con valor `0x31`), sino en cómo muestras lo que recibes.

Supongamos que se trata de un display que espera ASCII. Cuando recibe `0x31` mostrará el caracter que corresponda a ese código ASCII, y resulta que el caracter en cuestión corresponde al dígito `1`. Por tanto no es que "sólo" envíe el 1, sino que el `0x31` que ha recibido se *decodifica* como `'1'`.

Esto queda corroborado con el otro ejemplo que pones: `0x05` se muestra como un trébol. El ASCII `0x05` es un carácter de control, generalmente no imprimible, pero algunos dispositivos lo muestran [como un trébol](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/enquiry-clubs-card-suit-ascii-code-5.html)

Si lo que quieres es que, en el primer caso, el display te muestre `"31"`, eso significa que lo que tienes que enviarle son los códigos ASCII del `'3'` y del `'1'`. Pero entonces estarías enviando dos bytes (uno por dígito) por cada byte almacenado en el array. ¿De verdad es eso lo que quieres hacer?

En ese caso, puedes hacer algo de este estilo:

```
int i;
char buff[3];

for (i=0; i<6; i++) {
  sprintf(buff, "%02x", AxisDataMatrix[i]);
  HAL_UART_Transmit(**INDIFERENTE**, buff, 2, **INDIFERENTE**);
}
```

Comment: Hola muy buenas!! Sí, me funciona, me has entendido perfectamente. Mil gracias por la ayuda.